# As I'm new in ReactJs and don't no to face the errors of it and get this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

As I'm new in ReactJs and don't no to face the errors of it and get stuck in the problem as I'm trying to make a picture uploader in my Project. Please Guide me.. Thanks in Advance

**./src/App.js
SyntaxError: D:\webapp\src\App.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level. (44:0)**

42 |   );

43 | };

44 | export default App;
| ^

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { DateComponent } from './DateComponent';
import ImageUpload from 'image-upload-react'
import 'image-upload-react/dist/index.css'

const App = () => {
  
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState()

  const handleImageSelect = (e) => {
    setImageSrc(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
 
    return (
    <div className="form-style-5">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          <span className="number">1</span> Form
        </legend>
        <textarea name="field3" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        <DateComponent/>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          <span className="number">2</span> File Picker
        </legend>
      <div className="image">
        <ImageUpload
          handleImageSelect={handleImageSelect}
          imageSrc={imageSrc}
          setImageSrc={setImageSrc}
      style={{
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        background: 'gold'
      }}
       />
       </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: You are missing "} closing bracket" before "export default App;"

Answer (score -1):

In you code you miss closing bracket for const App = () => { }
kindly add a closing bracket at the end of App.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.